# How to run cron job dynamically in php

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have one file called report.php page.there i gave three options to user to select the cycles like daily,weekly,monthly.so if user select daily they will select time like 14:00 so i stored the cycle(daily) and time(14:00) in my database.

So i want to run the report page daily by 14:00 (24 hrs time).

if they select weekly i am showing time(15:00)and week(sun) so every sunday i want to run report.php page by 3pm

if they select monthly i am showing  date(1st) and time(16:00) so i want to  run every 1st day of month  by 4pm, i want to run that file

can anyone explain me how to do this.i tried but it's not working properly.i tried from past 2 days.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What code have you tried yet ?

Comment: i just get the time from database and i use if condition..if time meets it has to run file..i dont have that much of idea about it can you please explain clearly step by step if it is ok for you

Comment: What have you tried for the last two days?

Comment: first i  created one bat file there i gave my report.php page path and i created cron job in cmd so it will run every 5mins..so after next time i try to run every hour but its not running properly..so i started using dynamically..

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling this is exactly your problem. Basically the idea is there will be a file that is always running in background. This file will hit database and get all the jobs supposed to be triggered at that very specific minute and give them to some sort of worker scripts.

Comment: okay i will look at into that

Comment: @RaheelKhan can you please give me the example in php